# signal.h в windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, posix

Все источники говорят что, типы **sigaction**, **sigset_t** находятся в **signal.h**
Эта строчка у меня в самом верху присутствует:

```
#include <signal.h>
```

Но среда всё равно не видит **sigaction** и **sigset_t**. Пишет идентификатор не определён. Это потому что у меня OC Windows? Но **pthread.h** же работает. Можно ли здесь что-то сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Заголовочные файлы `csignal` в С++ и `signal.h` в С по стандарту содержат объявления только двух функции `signal` и `raise`. Все остальное - это расширения по спецификации posix или самопальные. `pthread.h` вообще нестандартный заголовок и если он у вас работает, то у вас просто установлена какая-то библиотека, эмулирующая интерфейс posix. Сигналы при желании тоже можно как-то реализовать, но зачем?

Comment: [ну вот здесь](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/ptkill.htm) в коде example есть **signal.h** и используется **sigset_t**

Comment: "Сигналы при желании тоже можно как-то реализовать, но зачем?" Нужно решить задачу : _Написать программу, которая создаёт новый поток(при помощи pthread_create()).Родительский поток(в котором был создан новый поток) должен послать дочернему(созданному) сигнал SIGINT.Дочерний поток должен перехватить этот сигнал и распечатать свой идентификатор(при помощи pthread_self()) и пришедший сигнал._

Comment: @zhukov Ну так а там прямо сказано *POSIX.4a*. `pthread_self` возвращает дескриптор потока а не идентификатор (thread id). На windows есть Windows Subsystem for Linux или Cygwin

Comment: А если `pthread_self` убрать (пусть дочерний поток печатает только пришедший сигнал), тогда можно будет решить без всего того, что вы написали?

Comment: @zhukov Такое задание явно предполагает выполнение его в POSIX-совместимой среде. Пытаться создавать такую среду самостоятельно - явно перебор.